# How to make direct API calls with Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am stumped (and feeling dumb).  I'm trying to simply make an API get call to an open API endpoint using Playwright and Typescript and not getting back a response body (or any errors).

```
import { test request, APIResponse } from '@playwright/test';

 test('api test', async ({request}) => {
    const response = await 
    request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`);
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: Hello, did you setup the configuration properly? You have to provide baseURL https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#configuration

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code, but it was missing a comma and it worked when a debugged it in  the test explorer as well as running from the cli terminal. Here is a simplified version:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

 test('api test', async ({request}) => {
    const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`);
    console.log(response.statusText());
  });
```

Here is the output after running npx playwright test:

```
Running 1 test using 1 worker
[chromium] › example.spec.ts:3:2 › api test
OK

  1 passed (2s)
```

Running npx playwright show-report your output will be in STDOUT. If you are using the Test Explorer, you will need to select the option **Reveal test output** which might be why you are not seeing anything. This hides terminal output by default.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using parse the response body and validate the response

```
 import { test, request, APIResponse } from '@playwright/test';

 test('api test', async ({request}) => {
 const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`);
 const statusCode = response.status() //get the status code
 console.log(statusCode)
 const responseBody = JSON.parse(await response.text())
 console.log(responseBody);
 console.log(responseBody.id) // using responseBody. you can do jsonpath to validate the value in the response
 });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `import { test request, APIResponse } from '@playwright/test';` is invalid syntax