# Any API request I try to make gives `apiRequestContext.fetch: Invalid URL`

Tags: playwright

Following documentation here: https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext

Even a simple get request to a free, public API gives `apiRequestContext.fetch: Invalid URL`

I tried this:

```js
page.request.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/0XYvRd7oD'
     ).then(res => console.log(res.body))
```

I even copied directly [from this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73979087/how-to-make-direct-api-calls-with-playwright) and it still gives `apiRequestContext.fetch: Invalid URL`

Is there some config I'm missing to be able to make these requests?

If you copy this and put it into your URL bar for a simple get request, it returns data. Why can I not get this in Playwrgiht?

https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/0XYvRd7oD

Here is my playwright config

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...nxE2EPreset(__filename, { testDir: './tests/playwright/e2e' }),
  fullyParallel: true,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: { baseURL, trace: 'on-first-retry', },
})
```

That said, page.goTo, page.click, page.fill are all working. I'm just not sure why page.request.get is not working

Comment: Works fine for me with `console.log(await res.json())`. `.body` is a function that returns a promise, so `await res.body()` is more appropriate. Are you on a corporate network or something?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work, I just used the default config provided from `npm init playwright@latest`

Before that I was using the default from

`'@nx/playwright/preset'`

Nx is still new and sometimes their documentation is super limited

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the "invalid URL" error. But I think you may have missed calling `.body()` as a function and `await`ing the promise it returns. Better yet, use `.json()` instead of `.body()` to parse it. The following code works fine for me:

```js
const {chromium} = require("playwright"); // ^1.38.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/0XYvRd7oD";
  const res = await page.request.get(url);
  console.log(await res.json());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
```

If this doesn't work for you, and https://www.example.com fails too, then perhaps provide more network/environment details and your full code so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, I am using Nx default config though 

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...nxE2EPreset(__filename, { testDir: './tests/playwright/e2e' }),
  fullyParallel: true,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    baseURL,
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },
})
```


That said, it seems to work fine when I navigate, everything like page.toGo and page.fill and page.click work, so I'm not sure why page.request.get doesn't work

Comment: Did you try with no config? Run this in a brand new project with a fresh install, package.json using playwright 1.38.0. What's `baseURL`? When sharing code, please share a fully runnable version with all imports, variables defined, package.json. 100% complete files, but with no extraneous information. Otherwise there's a lot of guesswork just to figure out how to reproduce your issue. Your link points to the Java docs, and from your first edit it wasn't apparent you were using playwright test.

Answer (score 0):

> No need to call Browser/page if you are directly validating on API
> level.**All you need is request [fixture](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures)**.This works for me:

```js
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
    
test('api test', async ({request}) => {
      const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`);
      console.log(await response.statusText());
});
```